# (Chernoff-type) tail bounds for beta distribution

Tags: concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

Assume $X$ has a symmetric $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\alpha)$ distribution,
where $\alpha$ is large.

Can we give strong tail bounds (similar to Chernoff bounds for the binomial distribution), i.e., bounds of the form 
$$
 \Pr\Bigl[\bigl|X-E[X]\bigr| \ge t \Bigr] \le \text{some small function of $t$ and $\alpha$?}
$$

Of course, one can use Chebychev's inequality, but intuition says, stronger bounds should be obtainable.
Also numerical experiments suggest that a bound of the form $e^{-C\cdot \alpha}$ holds.

*Attempts:*
It is known that for $\alpha=m\in\mathbb N$, $X$ can be written as
$$
X = \frac{E_1 + \cdots+ E_m}{E_1+\cdots+E_{2m}}
$$
where $E_i$ are i.i.d. $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ distributed; so $X$ can be written as a sum of variables, but they are not independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $t^{\alpha}(1-t)^{\alpha}$ is symmetric around $t=\frac{1}{2}$, the mean of a $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\alpha)$ random variable is always $\frac{1}{2}$, and accurate approximations for your probability just come from accurate approximations of the density function around $t=\frac{1}{2}$. Assuming $X\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\alpha)$, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}\left[\left|X-\frac{1}{2}\right|\geq t\right]&=&\frac{2\,\Gamma(2\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)^2}\int_{t}^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{4}-u^2\right)^{\alpha-1}\,du\\&=&\frac{\Gamma(2\alpha)(1-4t^2)^{\alpha-1}}{4^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(\alpha)^2}\int_{2t}^{1}\left(\frac{1-u^2}{1-4t^2}\right)^{\alpha-1}\,du\end{eqnarray*} $$
and the last integrand function can be approximated by $\exp\left(-(\alpha-1)\frac{4t(u-2t)}{1-4t^2}\right)$, leading to a Chernoff-type bound:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}\left[\left|X-\frac{1}{2}\right|\geq t\right]\leq\frac{\Gamma(2\alpha)(1-4t^2)^{\alpha}}{4^{\alpha}t(\alpha-1)\Gamma(\alpha)^2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
Since $\alpha$ is assumed to be large, another effective upper bound comes from replacing $t(1-t)$ with $\frac{1}{4}\exp\left(-(2t-1)^2\right)$, then exploiting the well-known [tail bounds of the normal distribution](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/normaltails/) (thanks to [Mike Spivey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2370/mike-spivey)).

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty usable! Can you give me a hint for the second-to-last step, i.e. how to bound this last integral?

Comment: @Sebastian: it is an usual argument: $\frac{1-u^2}{1-4t^2}$ equals $1$ at $u=2t$ and $0$ at $u=1$ (the endpoints of the integration range), so by computing the Taylor series of its logarithm, taking the first term and exponentiating back, we get a reasonable upper bound in terms of an easily integrable function.

Comment: I didn't think of that, nice! (Your writing style is quite concise ;) When I find time, I'll suggest an edit to include a few such details).